# Random sampling from a super level set

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, monte-carlo, random-generation

I have a random sampler from a region $X$. Suppose, I have a function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, where I can explicitly evaluate $f(x)$ and also obtain the gradient $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ easily (I mean less computational time).

What I want is random sampler from a super level set $X_{>\tau}=\{x \in X | f(x) > \tau\}$. Is there any good algorithm to do this?

I'm currently doing this by sampling from $X$ and then accepts if $x \in X_{>\tau}$ and otherwise reject. The problem is volume of $X_{>\tau}$ is so tiny and takes a lot of time for sampling from this region.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know a bit more about $f$. For example, if you knew it was [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), you could determine around each sample $x\notin X_{>\tau}$ a ball $B_x$ which would definitely be disjoint of $X_{>\tau}$, i.e. $B_x \cap X_{>\tau} = \emptyset$. And then you would only sample from $X\setminus \bigcap_{k=1}^K B_{x_k}$, where $x_k, k=1,\ldots, K$ are all the samples that did not happen to lie in $X_{>\tau}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my situation $X$ is not continuous, so ball cannot be defined ...

Comment: @orematasaburo How do you then define the gradient $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was wrong. $X$ is continuous. Creating a union of ball is interesting idea. Problem is $X$ is 1600 dimensional space. So, covering the region by balls seems to be intractable

Answer (score 0):

[Nested sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_sampling_algorithm) is an algorithm based on simulations from the prior over level sets
$$\{x;\ f(x)>f(x_0)\}$$where $f$ stands for the likelihood. The way the constraint is implemented is via a Markov chain Monte Carlo algorithm that starts from $x_0$ and makes a uniform proposal in the vicinity of $x_0$, &tc.